# Need Wiring diagram to Help Rewiring a Bedroom and Bathroom to prepare for smart home system

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom, ceiling-fan, bedroom

I need a wiring diagram to help with the re-wiring of a bedroom and bathroom. I will use 14/2 and 14/3 for all lights, then 12/2 and 12/3 for all outlets, ALL LIGHTS will be LED. The whole home will eventually be controlled by a smart system such as lutron radiora2 so I will be using smart switches etc.  Bedroom will have a ceiling fan with light combo on a 3 way switch with speed control and dimmer, I was thinking I would run power source 14/2 wire from main lug to switch A then run 2 pieces of 14/3 wire from switch A to Switch C which would be the end of the switch loop and from switch C then run a single 14/3 to the ceiling fan / light combo.  But from this point I need to get power to switch B and D which are for two separate closets which will have an LED light strip inside closet above door but I want the switch to control power to the light in each closet independently thus meaning that the ceiling fan light being on or off does not affect turning on or off the closet light. Question is what is the best way to wire this scenario.

Also

I would like to rewire the bathroom with a 2 gang box that would control a ceiling light with built in exhaust fan in center of bathroom, a recessed can light in shower stall, and a vanity light above sink. I was thinking one switch would control the shower light and exhaust fan seperately via a lutron one gang double switch then use the second gang to control the center ceiling light and vanity light both also independent via another lutron single gang double switc, thus having two switches controlling 3 separate lights and a exhaust fan all independently.  I also need to have a double gang GFCI near the sink for my wife and her hair dryer etc.  I actually have two bathrooms that are fairly close to each other and I am not sure if I can use one power source to feed the GFCI outlets used in both bathrooms or if each bathroom needs to be independent also not sure if I can run one 14/2 power source to control just the lights in both bathrooms since each bathroom is the same setup and the light will also be LED so not much of a draw.  As per code does all wiring for bathrooms need to be completely independent or can a bathroom share power from another bathroom. What would be the best way to wire this bathroom as shown in drawing attached.

Any and all help or drawings you could provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all in advance. I have attached drawings with notes for your information.

[image]

[image]

[!wiring digram for bedroom lights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIXF5.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIXF5.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Comment: hoe many breaker spaces can you free up in the main-lug panel? These will need to be full spaces, not halfsies.

Comment: Your diagram includes switched receptcles.  What switch  will they be controlled from? Do you imagine that switch having anything clever like dimming?

Comment: I am rewiring the entire house so I put in a new main lug.  I was thinking one power source run for lights with 14/2 and one run for outlets with 12/2  for each of the 3 bedrooms which have similar requirements. Thus each room on it's own dedicated breakers.  How many spaces or breakers do you thinking I would need?

Comment: The switched 1/2 hot outlets would be controlled by switch # A located at door # 1 and would be used for a lamp on each side of the bed to turn  light on or off etc.

Comment: Where is the homerun for the bathroom coming in at? Or were you envisioning it being on the same homerun as the bedroom? Also, do you have access to a good electrical supply house that can order things in, or are you stuck with big-box selection?

Comment: One more thing: do you have any oddball local Code requirements we should take into account here, or does your jurisdiction adopt the NEC straight-up (i.e. unamended or only administratively amended)?

Comment: So you want the switched half outlets to be controlled by the same 3-way switch complex that switches the light on the fan? Or will there be a separate switch at A?  Can you link the fan/ light controller you intend to use, I want to sanity check whether you can really "3-way" a fan/Light controller...

Comment: Are you ok running switch D and its light with 12AWG and having  it on a receptacle circuit?

Comment: @Harper -- if nothing else, the Lutron Maestro line has units that support that sort of setup...

Comment: Also, have you run the homerun already?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel i'm also trying to get a grasp on what wiring they need between them.   For instance running dual 14/3 between switch boxes gives a big buncha wire, but doesn't assure equal currents.

Comment: the homerun for the bathroom I was planning from above in the attic with a straight 14/2 run to the light switch for the lights and a straight homerun of 12/2  to the GFCI 2 gang outlet.

Comment: I dont think a bathroom can be on the same run as a bedroom for code reasons I believe they both have to be seperate.  I was planning on all 3 bedrooms and the two bathrooms having there own independent power source thus being each having one homerun for LED lighting with 14/2 wire and each having one homerun with 12/2 for all outlets.  I have access to both big box retail stores and also to actual electric supply houses where I would get my lutron / radiora2 products and others.

Comment: As far as code goes our township goes by NEC but we also have the worlds worst building inspector who does not know the difference between a roll of toilet paper and a roll of romex, seriously.  But as far as code goes I do everything to code or better so I am not looking to make any shortcuts that cost you later on.

Comment: the half hot switched outlets would be controlled by their own switch at doorway # 1 gang box # A, and the ceiling fan light combo would be controlled by a seperate switch that is a combo fan speed control / light dimmer switch all in one unit, thus there be two switches in a two gang box

Comment: the 3 way fan speed control / light dimmer would be controlled by the # A gang box and would definitely be seperate from the outlet switch. then the three way for ceiling fan would jump to door # 2 entrance where it would be a single gang companion switch for the ceiling fan/light.

Comment: As far as switch # D and running 12/2 from the nearby outlet to the switch for the closet light I guess it could be an optoin but I was trying to simplify and keep lights on one and outlets on another run but I am open to suggestions as long as they are code compliant and safe.

Comment: I have not run the wire yet but am ready to do it as soon as I have some plans showing me what can be done.  As far as the double runs of 14/3 from switch # A to Switch # C for the 3 way ceiling fan, I was planning on 2 runs because of wiring the fans and lights separately to be controlled separately on a single switch that has a top half for fan speed control and bottom half for light dimmer control.   then  I was wondering f I could jump off of the ceilingfan junction box to power the switches for both closet light switches.

Comment: I am open to any suggestions and would love to see any diagrams you could show me. As i would like to start this project first thing in the morning but I need to get a better understanding so as to get it done correctly and safely. Any and all assistance with this matter is greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 2):

### Bathrooms

Bathroom *fixed loads* like lighting and fan can be served by any convenient circuit.

With the bathroom receptacles, you have two choices.

- Many things, one bathroom:  The circuit serving receptacles in **one** bathroom can only serve other loads (fixed loads, lights, fan) in **that same** bathroom.  *or...*
- Many bathrooms, only receptacles:  A circuit may serve receptacles in **any number of** bathrooms, but it can serve **only** receptacles and **only** in bathrooms.

You can go either way.

### Switched receptacles

When having split receptacles (one unswitched, one switched)... the *usual* way that will be most understandable by "the next guy", and keep box fill sane, is to do switched receptacles is off the same circuit that powers the unswitched receptacles.  So in that case, you connect 12/3 between the two split receptacles, and from one split receptacle to the switch. *Remember, you need to carry /3 to a switch loop because you must bring neutral in a switch loop.  You cannot use neutral from the other circuit!!!*

Because you will have two different circuits in the same box, you must be very careful not to mix them.  You might even consider putting this switch in a different junction box, to remove all risk of confusion.

Having made the /3 connections between the two receptacles and the switch, you now can supply power in any of these locations - or really, anywhere else in the circuit.  Since I would be worried quite a lot about box fill in switch #1, I would consider feeding power into the receptacle circuit at the near receptacle.

Off the far receptacle (or anywhere in the circuit), you then continue with 12/2 cable carrying always-hot and neutral to other outlets.

*The second way to do it is to put these switched sockets on the lighting circuit.  In that case, the switch box would be all one circuit and that would ease box fill there.  But now you are running two complete circuits to the switched/split receptacles, although you can use /2 cable.  You will need to break off both the hot and neutral tabs and take care to keep separation of circuits.  Which will make box fill worse at the receptacles.*

### Closet lamp #4

Given the proximity of closet lamp #4 to a receptacle location, consider powering closet lamp #4 off the receptacle circuit instead of the lighting circuit. This will need #12 wire *because ALL wiring in a 20A circuit must be #12, no exceptions*.  It is totally legal to do this, it's just not recommended to put lighting on receptacle circuits *generally*, because if you overload a socket, the breaker trip will plunge you into darkness.  That's not a big issue on a single closet.

By the way, no receptacles allowed in closets, and lamps can't be where clothing can touch them.

### Box fill

Switches 1 and 3 are going to have a rather significant box-fill problem. I believe we discussed this six months ago on the three-fan circuit.  Be careful selecting your boxes so they are large enough, I'm fond of 4-11/16 square steel boxes and either 1-gang or 2-gang mud rings.

Comment: Harper, Thanks for the input much appreciated. I wanted to attach 2 drawings that I believe may be close to what your explaining but for some reason I cant attach any photos or drawings.  If you are able to sketch something out I would love to see what you have to share. thanks.

Comment: Harper. I have just attached 2 drawings that I believe may be close to what your explaining. please let me know what you think if possible

Comment: Yes, they look good.  Between the switch and the light, you only need 14/3 if the power enters at the light (if unsure it doesn't hurt to run it.)   Also if you have 39" to the right of closet 1, you do need a receptacle there.  Remember, you can use a tree topology (have incoming and TWO outgoing cables or even three).  If you don't know how to fork 3 wires on a receptacle, either use wirenuts or get the Leviton ProGrade sockets which accommodate 4.  That's a basic skill you should know.

Comment: all of my power will originate at the switch for all lights of which will all begin at box #A and branch off from there.  Between the switch and the light don't you need 14/3 for any future smart home applications switch wise and to meet neutral requirements at each switch. Thanks

Comment: Can I have a Code cite for "no receptacles in closets" please? It's definitely not in Art 406, where I at least was expecting to find it...

Comment: @Timberframer as long as the supply power (always-hot and neutral) comes into the switch, the requirement for neutral is satisfied.  The requirement is for smart *switches* not smart *lights* to be able to get neutral (and always-hot, since all switches need always-hot, obviously.)  The deadend spur to the lamp is allowed to be switched-hot and neutral only.

Answer (score 1):

### My take on this

I'm going to challenge three things here:

1. The use of two separate homerun cables into the bedroom -- they can be multiplexed into a single *two circuit* (12/2/2) cable (see the picture below for an example of what you're after -- it's also available in MC form, or you can simply pull a grey or striped 2nd neutral thru in a conduit job), especially since they're both going to the same box anyway!  This saves slightly on termination labor (one less cable to pull, one less ground wire to fuss with) and also facilitates the other two points here...
2. Using 14AWG wire for lights is somewhat silly from a Bill of Materials perspective -- having to order two extra spools of wire and also having leftover wires you can't use very well isn't a good trade for the slightly reduced copper costs you're getting here, and the extra box fill is relatively easy to accommodate given that you can get jumbo boxes these days.  So, my plan in this situation would be to use 12AWG for all the things.
3. Furthermore, the 12/3 cable is yet another Bill of Materials line item, and we need so little of it anyway, that it's better to replace it with a 12/2/2 with one of the neutrals retaped to be a hot (which is effectively a 12/4).  Thus, we can get this job done with only *two* spools of NM or MC: a spool of 12/2 and a spool of 12/2/2, as well as some electrical tape.  Less hassle keeping track of what cable goes where, less leftover wire, more uses for said leftover wire.

[image: 12/2/2 NM]

That being said, here's the diagram. 
[image: edited diagram showing wiring]

Lowercase letters (a, b, c) indicate which switch pairs with which light, while the numerals b1 and b2 indicate that it's a 3-way circuit.  Triple-hashes indicate a 12/2/2 cable with a neutral remarked as a hot, while the alternating long and short hashes (or the double arrow on the bedroom homerun) indicate an unaltered 12/2/2 cable.  Note that the 4th wire in the cable to the ceiling fan should be an always hot that's simply capped off at the fan (this means that someone can extend more lights from there readily if they want to in the future), while the extra wires in the cable going up to the bath fan should simply be capped off -- they're for if you want fancy bath fan controls in the future (there'd be enough room there if e and f were a double switch, freeing up a gang for the fan controller).

Last but not least, I'll one-up Harper's box suggestion -- since you have a supply house handy, Steel City/T&B and Garvin both make 5" square/2.875" deep metal boxes (Steel City 82181 or equivalent) -- these give you 64 in3 of wiring space, which is more than plenty for the two cable-heaviest switch boxes (A and C) in this design, especially when paired with a mud ring.